# How to read unsigned char delimited by white space in c

Tags: c, input, unsigned-char

As of now, when I try to load a unsigned char array with my input, each input character is treated as a char. How can I let the program know that I am entering unsigned chars into the input?

input: `86 75 178 98 75 15 78 88`

```
 unsigned char input[256];
 fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
 for(int i=0; input[i] != '\n'; i++){
   printf("%hhu ", (unsigned char) input[i]);
 }
```

The output as of now is "8 6  7 5  1 7 8  9 8...."

I would like to load up the `input` array with the numbers provided in the input.

Edit: would it be easier to use space as a delimiter to show the end of the first unsigned char?

Comment: You can use `strtol()` or `sscanf()` and friends to parse multi-digit numbers from strings.

Comment: You could use a formatted input function such as `scanf` or `sscanf`, or you could write some code to parse the input and perform string-to-int conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the buffer after reading it.  `"%n"` lets you know how far the scanning went.

```
unsigned char input[256];
if (fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin) == NULL) {
  HandleEOForIOError();
}

int n;
char *p = input;
unsigned char value;
while (sscanf(p, " %hhu %n", &value, &n) == 1) {
  printf("%hhu ", value);
  p += n;
}
if (*p != '\0') Handle_LeftOverGarbageInString();
```

Comment: Note: `"%hhu %n"` would have the same effect as `" %hhu %n"`.  No need for a leading space before `"%hhu"`, but a leading space in `" %n"` is needed for `if (*p != '\0') ...`.